# Windows 11 stores powershell history after sysprep with copyprofile true

Tags: windows, windows-11, sysprep

I've syspreped a Windows 10 computer using this command:

```
sysprep /oobe /generalize /shutdown /unattend:myfile.xml
```

My unattend file has the parameter: `<CopyProfile>true</CopyProfile>`

After I've syspreped a Windows 11 computer using the same command and the default users profile stores the powershell history and another information about the original user used when I syspreped.

Is something changed on Windows 11 Copyprofile behavior?

Comment: If you are copying user profiles, which is where the PowerShell console history is stored, what is the problem with the history being copied? I am confused by your question for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

Before and after `sysprep` you should setup the default user to contain
only the information you need.

Cleanup is absolutely necessary to remove unneeded data.
You should also set many Windows options to a logical setting.

Among other preparations, you could also delete the PowerShell history.
As the `Clear-History` command in PowerShell won’t clear the history
of the previous commands, use the following command to
delete the history file:

```
Remove-Item (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath
```

How to create a good sysprep image is too vast a subject to include here.
I suggest reading the following articles from persons who attempted
such settings. You are not obliged to do everything that they did,
but this should give you some idea of the possibilities.

- [Microsoft's CopyProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-copyprofile)
- [Windows 10 Default Profile set up](https://github.com/jeottesen/win10-default-profile)
- [Windows 10 Sysprep Issue](https://www.joseespitia.com/2016/03/25/windows-10-sysprep-issue/)
- [Creating a custom default profile on Windows 10 1803](https://james-rankin.com/articles/creating-a-custom-default-profile-on-windows-10-v1803/)